# fs.writefile дозаписывает файл вместо его перезаписи

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

Записываю файл с помощью fs.writeFile(), но при повторном использовании метода файл, вместо того чтобы перезаписываться - дозаписывается. Не могу понять причину :( Так же использую pm2, возможно в нем причина?

```
const data = Object.entries(oneObject).map(([key, value]) => ({ '#': `=${key}+1`, 'mail': value, 'formatted mail': `=REPLACEB(B2; 3; 3; "***")` }));

const fileString = await exportFromJSON({ data, fileName, exportType,  processor (content, type,   fileName) 
            {
            return content
            }

fs.writeFile(nameOfFile, fileString, (err) => err && console.error(err))
```

Изначально использовал метод fs.writeFileSync(). Понятное дело он дозаписывает файл, но судя по документации fs.writeFile() должен перезаписывать существующий файл.

Comment: Разница между writeFile и writeFileSync в том, что writeFile работает не в главном потоке. По коду все должно работать правильно, покажите, как вы запускаете программу

Comment: Программа работает через телеграм бота.

Я отсылаю ему запрос вида:
/contest PHPSSID

После чего срабатывает данный код:
bot.command('contest', async (ctx) => {

  serviceName = ctx.message.from.username

  // принимаем сообщение от клиента и распихиваем по переменным
  const dumpMessage = ctx.message.text.split(' ')
  phpToken = dumpMessage[1]
  numberOfPages = dumpMessage[3]

  await beScraped(phpToken, userId, numberOfPages)

  await ctx.replyWithDocument({
    source: nameOfFile
  })

Comment: Далее срабатывает метод beScraped() который парсит страницу, вытаскивает почты, записывает в файл и отправляет ответным сообщением в телеграм

Comment: магии нет. Если что-то попадает в файл, то оно было в fileString

Comment: Значит, самое простое - обнулять переменную fileString после записи фала? :)

Comment: перевел fileString из const в let, обнуляю в самом конце filestring = null, но все ранво при повторном использовании метода файл дозаписывается. Если в PM2 делаю restart - то фал записывается заново. Как понимаю - вся проблема именно в PM2 :(